# Cucumber scenario fails with Selenium but pass if disabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I'm in the process of setting up Selinium to work with Cucumber and Capybara in my Rails app.Currently, my env.rb configuration file contains only:

```
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
Cucumber::Rails::World.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

I'm not even sure if the second line is necessary ? 
The point is, I have `Given` step definition that creates Model data

```
Given /^a question named Question1$/ do
    @question = Question.create!(name: 'question1')
end
```

And, in view checkbox and label are created for that 'question1' entry.Now, `When` step definition is checking that checkbox:

```
check "question1"
```

and that scenario passes.
The problem is that when driver is switched to Selenium, the label and checkbox are not rendered on the page, as if `@question = Question.create!(name: 'question1')` is not executed, and that scenario fails:

```
Unable to find checkbox "question1" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. env.rb should contain

```
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the reason that you need to disable transactional fixtures is that Capybara runs its server on a different thread to your tests.  When transactional fixtures are on, your tests are wrapped in a transaction which is rolled back at the end of the tests.  Because that transaction is never committed, the other thread (Where Capybara is running its server) never sees the actions you take in the test.

Comment: Things are a bit different with Cucumber-rails installed, because it installs DatabaseCleaner by default, which allows transactional fixures to be turned off (by taking care of database cleaning for you)